# Is there a way to give certain document fields a weight in app engine full text search?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

In my application, I'd like the search API to value a match in the `name` field, higher than a match in the other fields.

A user can also fill in an 'about' message, which has way more text, so it could be more likely that a match happens there. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you please describe the problem you are trying to solve? I'm actually not clear on the scenario where this would be useful.

Comment: Let's say you have an e-commerce website, and you offer product search. Each product may have a title, a description and a "what's in the box" field. I want people to be able to seacrh the data for "power adaptor", so that power adaptors rank higher than products that state there's a power adaptor in the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SortExpression (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/sortexpressionclass) provides a way to set the sort based on a particular expression, but it only offers a document-wise score (i.e. not per field).

Another (probably bad idea) is to search only by name field, using a query string like "name: my_search_term_here"

So from my knowledge Search API of Google App Engine offers no way to bias one field during search (i.e. similar to the ^ operator in ApacheSolr Lucene).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of this functionality in Google AppEngine. Having said that, you could split this problem in two steps. First search for a term in name field, which would give you a list of documents, call it list1. Then search for the same term in less important fields. This would give you another list, call it list2. You can then combine these two lists in any way you want - i.e. make a new list3 which is a concatenation of list1 and list2 and all items from list1 are before items from list2. Hope this helps.